# Copying a file in .NET Core .csproj file

Tags: macos, .net-core, csproj

I created a new .NET Class Library project in .NET Core on Mac OS X. During the project build, I'd like to copy a file into the debug directory. How do I add this to the `.csproj` file?

```
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.1)

Product Information:
Version:            1.0.1
Commit SHA-1 hash:  005db40cd1

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Mac OS X
OS Version:  10.12
OS Platform: Darwin
RID:         osx.10.12-x64
Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with back to `.csproj` file the MSBuild is used again, this is can be done by MSBuild items. What you need is to add `CopyToOutputDirectory` attribute to the corresponding item and specify when to copy (Always, PreserveNewest, Never).

Example of the section in .csproj file (from [here](http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/01/19/project-json-to-csproj/)):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="notes.txt" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
    <!-- CopyToOutputDirectory = { Always, PreserveNewest, Never } -->

</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an error: "/code/code.csproj(5,11): error MSB4066: The attribute "Include" in element <None> is unrecognized."

Comment: @TrevorSullivan cannot get the same error, could you share more info please?

Comment: I'll see what I can get tomorrow if I can find some time. Thanks