# Create NuGet package with external .exe files using dotnet pack

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-core

**Edit: What I did to solve this:**

Created a new NuGet package with the following nuspec:

```
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>VIPSNuget</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>Devedse</authors>
    <owners>Devedse</owners>
    <licenseUrl>https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips/blob/master/COPYING</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Just the EXE file for VIPS</description>
    <releaseNotes>First release</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>VIPS exe file</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="VIPS\*.*" target="tools" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Placed all the .exe files in that folder.

Now from my ImageOptimizer I use the following code:

```
    var userProfileDir = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
    string pathVips = Path.Combine(userProfileDir, Constants.VipsDir, "vips.exe");
```

**Some Background**

I'm currently working on an Image Processing library that needs to convert an Image from JPEG to PNG using the external tool named VIPS. (https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips).

Since I didn't want to include the binaries from VIPS in my own project I thought, let's make a NuGet package of it where the .exe file can be called from my code.

**Steps I took**

I create a new dotnet core solution using the 'dotnet new console' command. After that I created a directory named "VIPS" and pasted all binaries in there.

I then created a nuspec file containing the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>Devedse</authors>
    <owners>Devedse</owners>
    <licenseUrl>https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips/blob/master/COPYING</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Just the EXE file for VIPS</description>
    <releaseNotes>First release</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>VIPS exe file</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="VIPS\*.*" target="tools" />
  </files>
</package>
```

I edited my .csproj file so that it only contained this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.0</TargetFramework>
    <Version>1.0.4.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>    
</Project>
```

**Problem**

Whenever I run the 'dotnet pack' command now, everything seems to go fine:
[image: NuGet package created]

But all the files from the VIPS directory are not included in my created nupkg:
[image: No tools directory]

(Reason why I chose tools is because in earlier versions of the dotnet framework / NuGet, I used tools like ILRepack that would be automatically installed in a tools directory which could then be called from a relative path of your deployed .exe file).

(Also see for example the nuspec code in https://github.com/gluck/il-repack/blob/master/build.gradle at line 92 where they also include the created .exe file in the 'tools' target)

**Further investigation**

What I then tried was to add all files from the VIPS directory into my csproj file and set the build action to Content.

All binary files now get included in the following 2 directories (so all duplicates which is also strange):
vipsnuget.1.0.0.nupkg\content\VIPS\
vipsnuget.1.0.0.nupkg\contentFiles\any\netstandard1.0\VIPS\

However when I now include the NuGet package inside another project, and then pack that project it seems to also include all binaries in that package again too:

[image: Big file size]

(All VIPS binaries are now placed inside: DeveImageOptimizer.1.0.0.nupkg\contentFiles\any\netstandard1.5\ and again in content\VIPS)

This isn't really desireable since the actual size of the DLL's in there should only be a few Kb's.

**Another issue with this approach**

I'm not actually sure if there's a good/better solution for this, but currently, when the NuGet package is restored, it will be extracted in %userprofile%.nuget\packages\vipsnuget...

So whenever I want to run a command against the VIPS.exe I need to point the Process.Start arguments to %userprofile%... . Is there a better way to do this? (E.g. find the place where NuGet packages are restored in code?)

**What I would like best**

Basically what I would like best, is to create a NuGet package where, if you include it, a certain directory will be copied to the build output of the project.

So something like:
DeveImageOptimizer\bin\debug\VIPS...

**If that doesn't exist**

If there's no way to do that, I would like to hear what the normal approach would be for putting certain 'tools' inside a NuGet package and calling them from inside C# code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `dotnet pack` without any arguments, it uses the `.csproj` file in the current folder to create a nuget package and ignore any `.nuspec` files. And if look into `dotnet pack` parameters you will not find how to specify `.nuspec` directly.

But, [dotnet-pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack) docs says we can provide MSBuild properties to the dotnet pack command for the packing process. From [NuGet metadata properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuget-metadata-properties):

> ***NuspecFile***
>
> Relative or absolute path to the .nuspec file being used for packing.
>   Note
>
> If the .nuspec file is specified, it's used exclusively for packaging
>   information and any information in the projects is not used.
>
> ***NuspecBasePath***
>
> Base path for the .nuspec file.

So modify your `.csproj` by adding the following

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <NuspecFile>location to your nuspec file</NuspecFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note: and you always could use `nuget pack` command directly.

Comment: That indeed solved my issue with the tools not getting included :). However, how can I now call the VIPS.exe file? Should I really call it in the Users\.....\.nuget directory? Or can I somehow let it be copied to the output directory of my program?

Comment: @Devedse look into [Set content files to “copy local : always” in a nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143817/set-content-files-to-copy-local-always-in-a-nuget-package). The main idea is to use `CopyToOutputDirectory` flag to [copy files to output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750318/copying-a-file-in-net-core-csproj-file/42751376#comment77551434_42751376)

Comment: so for that, would you have to include all DLL/EXE files inside the csproj file with Copy Local or can you also do that in the nuspec file?

Comment: And also, it looks like that I actually need to add the files as "Content" instead of "Tools" (reading from the posts you linked). If I do this, won't all the files be added to the NuGet package twice again? (Like it was the case in my first try)?

Comment: @Devedse: sorry, but not sure how to do this exactly. In general, I suggest asking a separate SO question for this problem, as now it sounds like "I have nuget packed with 3rd party files and want to use it from project that consume it"

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Thanks

Comment: @Devedse - if you asked a separate question, post the link here. I have a solution I can provide to that question if you haven't found a suitable answer.

Comment: @Devedse I also would like to know what approach you ended up implementing. Thanks.

Comment: See my initial comment, I added some more information there :)